# How merge two the same strings of lenght with delta in postgresql?

Tags: string, postgresql, string-concatenation

For example, I have the strings `oaaoaa` and `aoaoao`.
I need the result: `ooaoao`.
That is, it is necessary that the lines merge into one.
At the same time, the common part of the lines was preserved, and the mismatch was replaced by the symbol

How can this be done in Postgresql?

I try make this:

```
select 'text' | 'text'
```

but but of course got an operator error.

Comment: Would the input strings _always_ have only letters `a` and `o`?

Comment: in my present situation it is. There are only two characters.

Comment: The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||`  (not `|`)

Comment: What is the logic for oaaoaa and aoaoao to become ooaoao. Please try to explain this.

Comment: || falling to the result "ooaaaaaaaaa".
I need a process similar to logical OR with binary numbers, only with strings where there are only two characters

Comment: Explain the logic - in the question. There  is an edit  for this purpose. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75863710/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chose the wrong data type. You should have taken `varbit` rather than `text` or `varchar`, then the `|` would have done just what you want. You can still achieve your goal by translating the characters to 0 and 1 and casting the data to `varbit':

```
SELECT translate(
          CAST (
             CAST (translate('oaaoaa', 'ao', '01') AS varbit) |
             CAST (translate('aoaoao', 'ao', '01') AS varbit)
             AS text
          ),
          '01', 'ao'
       );

 translate 
═══════════
 ooaoao
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

This iterates over each character position of the strings by generating a series of the length, so both strings must be the same length. If any character in a position is o then o else a.

```
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(
        CASE 
            WHEN POSITION('o' IN string1) = position OR POSITION('o' IN string2) = position THEN 'o'
            WHEN SUBSTRING(string1 FROM position FOR 1) = 'a' AND SUBSTRING(string2 FROM position FOR 1) = 'a' THEN 'a'
            ELSE 'o'
        END,
        ''
    ) AS result
FROM 
    (SELECT 'oaaoaa' AS string1, 'aoaoao' AS string2, generate_series(1, LENGTH('oaaoaa')) AS position) t
```

| result |
| --- |
| ooaoao |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VQphIKuw)